# Php mysql include a row id in another row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database where i'd like to include the contents of a row in another row. The content of all my rows is static html. I am looking for something similar to the 'include' command.

This is an example:

```
Row 1=A
Row 2=fast
Row 3=red
```

In Row 4 i have the content 'car'. I need to include the content of row 1, 2, and 3 before the content of row 4. Therefore the output would be A fast red car.

Is this possible? I only have one database, so there are not external references.

My mysql knowledge is near zero. My programmer was lazy and copied all the same html to each row. So now when i update i have to update the static html in many rows.

Thanks

Comment: Why on earth do you have HTML in your database?

Comment: Oh no! You shouldn't write your app the way you do. Why do you store html in sql? Lol

Comment: @metal_fan can you enlighten me a bit why not store html in a database?

Comment: @Kyokasuigetsu Actually - You can always store/generate html in database - but this is worst practice I ever faced because 1) You always need establish the link (what if connection fall because of server overload?!) 2) You need to select database => you need generate query => you need to check for some conditions (as usual) etc etc... This is just dirty and anti MVC pattern. This will make your code just illegible for follow debug /maintain. Really. Take a look at popular product written in PHP - they use logic(classes, functions) separately from it's view. View is bunch of HTML files (usual)

Comment: mmm, i need a new programmer then

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @metal_fan thanks for the enlightenment.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do something like this:

```
$query = mysqli_query($database_connection, "SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 4");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

echo $row['column_name']; }
```

I hope this is what you mean.

Comment: I forgot: change the first line to this: $query = mysqli_query($database_connection, "SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 4 ORDER BY column_name ASC"); which will get you row 1 first, then row 2 etc...

Comment: Ok, sorry for my ignorance, but  have no idea how i can modify your code to include row ids?

Comment: How does the structure of your table look like? How many columns are there?

Comment: I have 6 columns and around 300 rows. My order cannot be ASC as some of the IDs are not in order.

Comment: My insert command would be something like this:

<insert id 4, 6, 13>

NEW TEXT

Comment: Take the name of the column where the values "a", "red", "car" are stored and rewrite the first line I wrote with: $query = mysqli_query($database_connection, "SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 4 ORDER BY column_name ASC"); where column_name is the column with the values you need to display in order.

Comment: One thing you could do is make an array of these values and then make a foreach loop where you select the value from the particular column and display it.

Comment: Say i have five rows in my table (ID1-5)

In the fifth row (ID5), how can i include the content of all of the four previous rows before the html content stored in the fifth row? this is what i'm trying to do, not call a row to a php file.

Comment: I'm affraid I don't quite understand you. Why not just echo the values in order from 1-5?

Comment: In my answer I wrote how to echo the values, just change the table_name, column_name and such and you're good to go. What the code snippet does is basically looping through and receiving values from the database. The part "LIMIT 4" means that it should loop 4 times, getting the values from the first 4 rows in the table.

Comment: Ok, i wrote in the header of row 5:

echo $row['articles']; }

Where do i include row number 1 in this statement?

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but the limit 4 will not work as i need to include one or two rows inthe 300 rows in random parts. The database has been poorly put together by the developer.

Comment: If static content is going to be included I would recommend to take the time and just rewrite it to plain html, since the randomness of the rows and values would make it necessary to create an array and then loop through it with foreach and the echo the values from there. This could of course work, but what if you need to change something in the future, maybe the order of the values or something like that. There's no need to use a database here, and even though it maybe is a lot of work, it will pay of later since the code will be much easier to work with without the database involved.

Comment: ok, but even if i include a, <?php include ''page.php''; ?>, it still doesnt show the content. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what the exact problem may be since you provided so little code, but I'd use require_once('page.php'); . I have used it for years and it hasn't been any problems.

Comment: mmm still no luck. It just ignores all php code. Perhaps thats why your original code doesn't work either.